# i want to calculate the T(n) for the two algorithms

Tags: c++, c++11, data-structures

i want to know the time complexity for the following two algorithms

```
void main (){-----------------------------------------T(n)
for(int a=1 ; a<=20 ; a++) {------------?
if(a%2==0)  -------------?
    cout<<"value is Even"; --------?
   else 
     cout<<"value is Odd";--------?
}
```

}

```
void main (){-----------------------------------------T(n)
int x=1; {------------?
int a=1;  -------------?
   while(a<=n){--------?
   x=x*a; -------------?
   a=a+2; -------------? 

}
cout<<x;
}
```

Comment: Isn't time complexity termed _O(n)_ traditionally?

Comment: what is your take? Post what you have done/considered and someone can guide you? Just asking for someone to solve your homework is kind of bad.

Comment: i wish i knew how but i truly don't know how but thanks

Comment: Do you know what Time Complexity means to start with?

Comment: no sir  i want to learn programming and i took an online course about data structure and they gave us this homework and i dont realy know how to solve it

Comment: If your new to programming, it's a stupid homework. Concentrate on learning the basics of programming. Then the performance can be added later. Anyway - I'll try to explain the idea in an answer. Hope it helps. Have fun.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is to calculate how the execution time for a piece of code - typically some algorithm, depends on the input. If a function takes N as input how long will it take to execute if N=5 or N=10. Will it take double as long? Will it take the same time? Or will it take more than double?

In your case:

The first program doesn't depend on any input so it is O(n)=1.

Your second program depends on n. It will do the same stuff n/2 times due to the a = a + 2. So it is O(n)=n/2. However constants are typically skipped and one would write O(n) = n.

If you had code like this:

```
for (a=0; a < n; a++)
{
     // n times here
     for (b=0; b<n; b++)
     {
        // n times here

        // do something
     }
 }
```

the execution time will change to n^2 because both loops will iterate n times. Each time the outer loop executes, the inner loop executes n times. Since the outer loop executes n times, you have n*n. So O(n) = n^2

Comment: i will be thankful to u for the rest of my life i am really grateful

Answer (score 1):

### Calculate the complexity

You need to add the **basic operations**/**machine instructions** that are being executed. (as a function of the size of it's input)

### 1st Case

```
void main ()
{
for(int a=1 ; a<=20 ; a++)
      |         |      |
     c1         c2     c3
{
if(a%2==0) --c4 (the cost of whole if-else construct)               
    cout<<"value is Even"; 
   else 
     cout<<"value is Odd";
}
```

}

c1,c2,c3,c4 are the costs to execute the machine instructions corresponding to these constructs (like a<=20,etc)

```
Look carefully the cost is
 = c1+ c2*(20+1) + c3*20+c4*20;
 = c1+21*c2+20*c3+20*c4
 = constant.

So, T(n)=O(1)
```

Why 20+1? Oh! that is because of the last check when actually `a=21`.

### 2nd Case

For this code check it out similarly

```
void main ()
{
 int x=1;--c1
 int a=1;--c2
   while(a<=n)--c3
   {
   x=x*a; --c4
   a=a+2; --c5
   }
cout<<x;  --c6
}
```

> Now the cost is = c1+c2+c3*(n+1)+n*(c4+c5)+c6
>                   = n*(c3+c4+c5)+ (c1+c2+c3+c6)
>                   = A*n+B (A=constant, So is B)

So T(n)=O(n).

> Remember we are only interested in performance upto constant factors. That's why we ignore the constants like A,B etc. We can multiply or divide them with constant factor to get simpler form.

Comment: Good answer. More detailed than my answer and probably also more like the way it is done in the text books these days.

Comment: @nielsen.:Thanks nielsen.