# Simple time-complexity problems

Tags: java, time-complexity

I need to know the complexity of these two bits of code.

```
public static int Sum(int x, int y){ 
return y*(y+1)/2 - (x-1)*x/2;
}

public static int RecSum(int x, int y){ 
if (x < y+1)
    return x + RecSum(x+1, y);  
else
    return 0;    
}
```

I have it as Sum being O(n^2) and RecSum being O(n).

Am I correct?

Comment: Is this homework, by any chance ?

Comment: that would depend on what n is

Comment: Your second method should either run once or forever it would seem.

Comment: Yeah this is homework, I am just a bit confused with it and was wondering if I was correct. The second method works fine also.

Comment: @SashaSalauyou, the first is O(1), but the second is not, on account of its recursion.  (The second is O(y).)

Comment: @JohnBollinger yes, my fault. O(n)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you take a look at Sum() how does the number of loops change when the input change? Sum() only performs 1 calculation regardless of the input. In other words - the execution time is constant regardless of input. Consequently you have O(1).

RecSum() calls itself. The number of times depends on the difference between y, x. So if that difference doubles, the execution time doubles. So you have O(n)

Maybe this could be useful too [i want to calculate the T(n) for the two algorithms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29319928/i-want-to-calculate-the-tn-for-the-two-algorithms/29320435#29320435)

Comment: Thank you very much, makes perfect sense the way you explained it.

Comment: @Chriskaz accept the answer if you like it, that's how things are done at SO.